# How can I pass the selected values from the dropdown list to the url query string when button submit is clicked?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want the $module_id and $user_name be passed to the url.

The code below does not pass the correct values from the dropdown list to the URL query string. Can you please show me what's missing?

```
    <?php
    $root = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    $fullname = $_POST['user_name'];
    $user_name = explode(" ", $fullname);
    $module_id = $_POST['e_learning_module'];
    ?>                          
                        <form action="<?php echo home_url() . '/certificate/print-request-certificate.php?id=' . $module_id . '&fname=' . $user_name[0] . '&lname=' . $user_name[1]; ?>" method="post" name="">
<select id="user_name" name="user_name">
<option value="default">Names</option>
<?php
$query = mysql_query('SELECT DISTINCT fname, lname FROM wl_activity_logs ORDER BY fname ASC');

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
echo '<option value="' . htmlentities($row['fname'], ENT_QUOTES) . ' ' . htmlentities($row['lname'], ENT_QUOTES) . '">' . htmlentities($row['fname'], ENT_QUOTES) . ' ' .  htmlentities($row['lname'], ENT_QUOTES) . '</option>';
}
?>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="user_name" id="user_name_hidden">

<select id='e_learning_module' name="e_learning_module">
<option value="default">E-Learning Modules</option>
<?php
global $post;
$args = array(
'numberposts' => -1,
'post_type' => 'wpsc-product',
'post_status' => 'publish',
'wpsc_product_category' => 'e-learning-modules',
'order' => 'ASC'
);
$e_learning_modules = get_posts($args);

foreach( $e_learning_modules as $post ) { 
                                    setup_postdata($post);
$id = $post->ID;
?>
<option value="<? echo $id; ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></option>
<?php 
}
?>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="e_learning_module" id="e_learning_module_hidden">

<input type="submit" value="Print" name='print' />
</form>
```

Comment: Why do't you add them as hidden field. The form method is POST and using the $_POST the values could be catched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haave to use form methode as 'get' (`method="get"`) as below.

```
<form action="<?php echo home_url() . '/certificate/print-request-certificate.php?id=' . $module_id . '&fname=' . $user_name[0] . '&lname=' . $user_name[1]; ?>" method="get" name="">
```

Comment: `?e_learning_module=351&e_learning_module_hidden=&user_name=Amanda+Walker&user_name_hidden=&print=Print` 

Thanks! I would like to get 351 and Amanda+Walker only, how do i do that?

Comment: you can achieve this by removing below input hidden elements.

`<input type="hidden" name="e_learning_module" id="e_learning_module_hidden">
    <input type="hidden" name="user_name" id="user_name_hidden">`

Answer (score 2):

Change

`<form action="<?php echo home_url() . '/certificate/print-request-certificate.php?id=' . $module_id . '&fname=' . $user_name[0] . '&lname=' . $user_name[1]; ?>" method="post" name="">`

To

`<form action="<?php echo home_url() . '/certificate/print-request-certificate.php" method="GET" name="">`

Add the following code below form tag

`<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $module_id?>">
<input type="hidden" name="fname" value="<?php echo $user_name[0]?>">
<input type="hidden" name="lname" value="<?php echo $user_name[1]?>">`

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 fields with same name 'user_name':

`<select id="user_name" name="user_name"></select>`

and

`<input type="hidden" name="user_name" id="user_name_hidden">`

You need to change the second one to another name (E.g: `user_name_hidden`) or change the first one to another name (eg: `full_name`) then use `$fullname = $_POST['full_name'];`

Comment: Thank you. But it didn't picked up the selected value from <select>

Comment: Because you have 2 fields with same name. In such case, only value of the last field in form will be retrieved. In your form, the hidden field is the last one with empty value. That's why the value from `<select/>` will not be retrieved. That's why you have to rename one of the two fields. You can try changing `<input type="hidden" name="user_name" id="user_name_hidden">` to `<input type="hidden" name="user_name_hidden" id="user_name_hidden">` and you will see your desired result!

Comment: Also, do NOT change form method to GET as $_POST will become useless (empty).